# Calculate x and z force for jump in 3d space

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I want to make character jump in direction of camera. At the moment I am applying force through vector, y / vertical is const, but how to calculate for x and z ratio ?

```
rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(10.0f,  JumpForce, 10.0f), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

I want to make possible to jump in 3d space from rock to rock, to be parabolic by influence of gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "jump in direction of camera", but as I understand it do something like this:

```
Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - camera.transfrom.position;
Vector3 clampedDirection = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (direction, 10f);
Vector3 forceVector = new Vector3 (clampedDirection.x, 10f, clampedDirection.z);

rigidbody.AddForce(forceVector, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

By this you will get vector of direction from jumping player to camera, and its length will be clamped to 10f. The `forceVector` will have x and z from clamped vector and y will be constant 10f. If you want to have `forceVector` be also 10f of its length, just clamp it too:

```
Vector3 forceVector = Vector3.ClampMagnitude (forceVector, 10f);
```